# An ambiguous reference between two library components?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

Currently, I have implemented two libraries, Radzen and AntDesign.Charts to test out graphical visualizations.

However, it seems that there is an reference between these two libraries' components.

Here is the error message:

`error CS0104: 'TextStyle' is an ambiguous reference between 'Radzen.Blazor.TextStyle' and 'AntDesign.Charts.TextStyle' [D:\AntblazorCharts\AntblazorCharts.cspro j]`

***Razor Page:*** (The only component on the page)

```
<AntDesign.Charts.Line Data="data" Config="config"/>
```

***_Imports.razor***

```
@using Radzen
@using Radzen.Blazor
@using AntDesign.Charts
```

How can I deal with this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you use full name for the component to distinguish references to these two? We would need to see the offending code to help you out.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I have tried to use the full name. I was basically just using a Line Chart component and there is nothing else on the razor page. However, it still returns the same error.

Comment: What file/linenumber is reported in the error?

Comment: I think is because you're importing both libraries in your _imports file.

Comment: That's my guess too, @GuilhermeMolin.  I learned the hard way, just because global includes exist, doesn't mean you should use them.  I find it much better to put separate `using` statements in each file-- that makes me constantly think about my file structure, organization, etc.

Comment: Which file is getting this error?

Comment: Just choose the correct one and write the complete reference

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to `Guilherme Molin` and `Bennyboy1973`.

Do not include all the libraries which could cause conflicts in _Imports.razor.

Only import them when they are needed, and use the full name for the component in the way suggested by `maciek`.